# Can't upload multiple files to a folder?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use this code to upload multiple files to my root folder, but I just keep getting the files with the error field being 1, what can I do?

I'm really just beginning to use php so I don´t know what to do or how wrong this code may be.

```html
<form action="upload-script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>Nombre del proyecto</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="nombre_proyecto" placeholder="Escribe aquí el nombre de tu proyecto..." required></p>
        <p>Descripción del proyecto</p>
        <p><textarea name="desc_proyecto" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Escribe aquí el contenido que describirá a tu proyecto..."></textarea></p>  
        <p>Construcción del proyecto</p>
        <p><textarea name="constru_proyecto" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Describe cómo se realiza paso a paso éste proyecto..."></textarea></p>  
        <p>Metodología del proyecto</p>
        <p><textarea name="met_proyecto" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Explica a otros docentes con detalle, qué metodología aplica éste proyecto y porqué funcionó..."></textarea></p>  
        
        
       

    <h1>Tags del proyecto</h1>
    <p>Éstas describirán de qué asignaturas está compuesto el proyecto</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Mecanica">Mecanica</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Electronica">Electronica</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Fisica">Fisica</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Biologia">Biologia</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Anatomia">Anatomia</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Ciencias">Ciencias</p>

<p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
        
    <div class="submit-class">
      <button name="submit" value="submit">¡Compártelo!</button>
        </div>


<?php
include ('../includes/Main-header.php');
    if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
        
        var_dump($error_array);
        
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "../project-files/".$name_array[$i])){
            echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }
    }
        
}
     

include('../includes/main-footer.php');
?>
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: per the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) - `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.`. So what is your `upload_max_filesize`?

Comment: change this    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
<p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
<p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
```

with

```
<p><input type="file" name="file_array" multiple></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple files can be selected and then uploaded using the

```
<input type='file' name='file[]' multiple>
```